# Facing issue while Building GRPC on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, grpc

While  Building GRPC on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS ..below are the command we are using :
cd /usr/local/src/grpc
git submodule update --init --recursive
mkdir -p cmake/build
cd cmake/build
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -    DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ../..

Below error i am getting and it get stop:

```
[ 34%] Linking CXX shared library libprotoc.so
[ 34%] Built target libprotoc
```

make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2

I have tried Building

Comment: How long have you waited for it to finish? How many cores does you machine have? How much memory does your machine have?